# Function for comparing two cell arrays

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array (2000*10) with each cell containing a string such as `'25:20:55'`.

I want to write a function that accepts 10 inputs (say `'25:02:33'`, `'58:69:88'`, `'25:54:96'`, `'48:58:36'`, `'58:54:88'` and so on) and looks for a match in each column corresponding to input value for that particular column (i.e. the first input data corresponds to 1st column, 2nd to 2nd column of the stored data and so on.

How can I write a function for the above comparison?

Comment: Do the cells contain strings such as "25:20:55" or do you mean the cells contain arrays like `[25, 20, 55]`?

Comment: It has strings like '25:20:55'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cell array contains strings, you can find matches using `strcmp`:

```
input = {'25:02:33', '58:69:88', '25:54:96', '48:58:36', '58:54:88'};
match_idx = strcmp(repmat(input, size(cell_data,1),1), cell_data);
```

If you only want to know if there are matches in the respective columns at all and do not care about the line index of the match, you can do

```
match = any(match_idx,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ismember`

```
ismember(your_var, your_cell);
```

e.g.

```
c = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
ismember('b', c)
 ans =
     1
ismember('q', c)
ans =
     0
```

In your case, something like could work

```
function arr = myfun(inputvec, inputmat)
for i=1:length(inputvec) %// where inputvec is the cell-vector with the strings you want to search for
   arr(i) = ismember(inputvec{i}, inputmat{:,i});
end
```